# Will a SQLite database use more RAM as its size gets bigger?

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core

I use SQLite as database in my ASP.NET Core app. The overall database volume is 227 MB. If I remove blobs from database, its size comes down to 147 MB.

If this database size reaches to 5 GB in the long run, does it mean that I need at least 5 GB of free RAM to run my ASP.NET Core app?

Comment: Why do you think SQLite would need to keep the whole DB in memory?

Comment: DB size does not have a 1 to 1 relationship with RAM availability (unless you are explicitly configuring a RAM disk to run it on).

Comment: Only if you're trying to do something like update every single database record in one giant transaction.  Even then, the data would get swapped to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite **reads and writes directly to ordinary disk files** unless you use the [In-Memory Database Mode](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

For more info look at [About SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html).

Comment: It has an in memory cache so it doesn't have to read from disk as much; the size is controlled with the [`cache_size` pragma](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size)